# Boolean function in Scala depending on another method

Tags: scala, boolean

I need to write a function 'result' that if some method B returns the empty list, method 'result' should return true, else false.

but the ouput is not as desired. Any ideas of the mistake? Thanks

Comment: It is not printing the desired result. Function 'B' returns List() or List(index1,index2,Set(somevalues). I need to make function 'result' return true when function 'B' returns just List(), false otherwise. In this case it is always giving false

Comment: That is surprising. I don't think it should be doing that. Please show some evidence.

Comment: Can you show the function B?

Comment: Why did you delete your original code? It was correct!!

Comment: I've just tested your code and if B is defined as `def B() = List()`, `result` will return `true`. I think your issue is with `B`, not with `result`.

Answer (score 3):

You can check for an empty list with `isEmpty`:

```
def result(): Boolean = ! B().isEmpty
```

alternatively you could match on the list returned from `B`:

```
B() match {
    case Nil => puzzle
    case _ => solve(state())
}
```

Comment: To be a little picky, your second case could be "case _ => ..." :)

Comment: @vptheron - Yes good point, it's a bit strange the result from `B` isn't actually used.

Comment: to be fair the whole exercise seems a bit strange :) I don't know why 'result' is needed.